# How to get the sum of the three column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

My problem is how to get the single output value as three different column value sum as total sum of the all the column

leave count of casual leave

```
SELECT SUM(casual_leave_days) AS casual_leave  
                FROM leaveapplydata
                WHERE emp_id = '".$_POST["emp_id"]."' AND casual_holiday_start
                LIKE '$passyear%'
```

leave count of vaction leave

```
SELECT SUM(vaction_leave_days) AS vaction_leave 
                FROM leaveapplydata
                WHERE emp_id = '".$_POST["emp_id"]."' AND vaction_holiday_start
                LIKE '$passyear%'
```

leave count of other leave

```
SELECT SUM(other_leave_days) AS other_leave 
                FROM leaveapplydata
                WHERE emp_id = '".$_POST["emp_id"]."' AND other_holiday_start
                LIKE '$passyear%'
```

now i want get total holiday count in pass year using single query.how do i do it?
table structure

```
tbl_id  emp_id  casual_leave_days   casual_holiday_start    casual_holiday_end  vaction_leave_days  vaction_holiday_start   vaction_holiday_end other_leave_days    other_holiday_start other_holiday_end   leave_reason    applicant_sign  actor_sign  supervior_sign  head_sign   
1   23  9   2019-12-23  2019-12-27  0   0000-00-00  0000-00-00  0   0000-00-00  0000-00-00  Private 1   1   1   1   
2   23  2   2019-12-24  2019-12-26  0   0000-00-00  0000-00-00  0   0000-00-00  0000-00-00  Private 1   1   1   1   
3   23  0   0000-00-00  0000-00-00  2   2019-12-28  2019-12-30  0   0000-00-00  0000-00-00  Sickness    1   1   1   1   
4   23  1   2019-12-29  2019-12-30  1   2019-12-30  2019-12-31  0   0000-00-00  0000-00-00  Private 1   1   1   1   
5   25  1   2019-12-30  2019-12-31  0   0000-00-00  0000-00-00  0   0000-00-00  0000-00-00  Other   1   1   1   1   
6   30  1   2020-01-01  2020-01-02  0   0000-00-00  0000-00-00  0   0000-00-00  0000-00-00  Private 1   1   1   1   
7   30  5   2019-11-04  2019-11-11  0   0000-00-00  0000-00-00  0   0000-00-00  0000-00-00  Private 1   1   1   1   
8   23  1   2020-01-02  2020-01-03  0   0000-00-00  0000-00-00  0   0000-00-00  0000-00-00  Sickness    1   1   1   1
```

Comment: You can do SELECT `SUM(casual_leave_days + vaction_leave_days + other_leave_days)..`

Comment: okay bro i will check your idea

Comment: Well problem is that, you have dedicated dates, I would suggest, restructuring your table. like having vacation_type and have vacation_start, vacation_end. that way id would be easier and cleaner structure

Comment: yes bro i also think about it.thank you idea

Comment: Regardless of how you address this, please Google "SQL injection". Your code has a security hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summing is commutative, so you could add the three fields and then sum them:

```sql
SELECT SUM(casual_leave_days + vacation_leave_days + other_leave_days) AS total_leave  
FROM leaveapplydata
-- WHERE some condition
```

Comment: Cool man but OP have separate date range fields for each type of vacation

Comment: As there is different column for each type of leave, just take union of above queries with same alias for leave count and take sum of leave group by emp_id

Comment: @Mureinik . . . `SUM()` and `+` are not interchangeable (the property name isn't "commutative" because that refers to only a single operation but I know what you mean) because of `NULL` values.  Without `NULL`s, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this ,

```
SELECT (casual_leave  + vaction_leave + other_leave_days  ) AS total_leave 
FROM (
SELECT SUM(casual_leave_days) AS casual_leave , 
       SUM(vaction_leave_days) AS vaction_leave , 
       SUM(other_leave_days) AS other_leave
FROM leaveapplydata
WHERE emp_id = '".$_POST["emp_id"]."' AND  (casual_holiday_start LIKE '$passyear%'
OR vaction_holiday_start LIKE '$passyear%'
OR other_holiday_start ) )
```